# Makefile error: Unexpected end of line seen

Tags: git, makefile, solaris, sun, sunos

Trying to install Git, I ran configure and make, but got the following error message:

> make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile,
>   line 221: Unexpected end of line seen

The Makefile looks like:

```
218:    GIT-VERSION-FILE: FORCE
219:            @$(SHELL_PATH) ./GIT-VERSION-GEN
220:    -include GIT-VERSION-FILE
221:
222:    uname_S := $(shell sh -c 'uname -s 2>/dev/null øø echo not')
```

What's causing the error?

The following information may or may not be relevant:

- I tried to install Git 1.7.0.3 on
  SunOS 5.9 (Solaris 9) in a directory in my account.
- The gcc version is 3.4.2 (older then the
  version of 3.4.6 stated by
  sunfreeware.com).
- I don't have root privileges.

Comment: The make version would be more relevant than the gcc version. Perhaps it's too old to support the `-include` directive?

Comment: @Jefromi: or it isn't GNU Make...the Sun Make probably does not understand '-include' - and will be expecting either a colon or an equals sign on line 220 (since it can't be a command because the first character is not a tab), and all other lines are comments, rules (with a colon) or macros (with an equals) and line 220 doesn't fit any of those.

Comment: If your Makefile really says `øø` then it somehow became corrupted.  It should be `||`.  Try downloading again.

Comment: @mark4o: maybe Winston is working with a Scandinavian (Danish?) code set where ø appears at the code point where | appears in 8859-1.

Comment: @ Jefromi, Jonathan Leffler: Here is the information about make: RELEASE VERSION SunOS 5.9 Patch 111703-03 October 2002.

@mark4o, Jonathan Leffler: I don't know how the || got changed. Maybe from copying and pasting, or I hit the wrong keys.

After your comments, I used gmake (3.80, from 2002) and got error messages about include files and openssl. Do I have to ask root to install dependencies? Or can I install them locally and tell gmake where to look for them?

Answer (score 11):

Using `gmake` on SunOS instead of `make` fixed this issue for me.

Comment: also change the line      "= cc" to instead be "= gcc"

Comment: Same answer already answered before you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557787/makefile-error-unexpected-end-of-line-seen/23390765#23390765

Answer (score 6):

Use `gmake` instead of `make`.

Genrally solaris has two command, `gmake` and `make`. In this `gmake` is GNU style make command, and `make` is solaris style make command. I hope you have written your makefile in GNU style. So use `gmake` command.

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to DOS line endings (CRLF) in your makefile. I have just had a similar problem and solved it by running dos2unix on the makefile. Linux make seems unfazed by the same makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have actually tabbed the line and it is not all spaces. I had this issue but I found out the command was not properly tabbed in and that is why I was running into this error.

Comment: @Diavolche: Only the beginning of Line 219 in the code excerpt has a tab.

Comment: In my case the line wasn't properly indented (should start with a tab). Why this was -1'ed is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Its a problem with your "make", install "make-3.81.tar" and then try

Answer (score 1):

I came to this error with 2 simple makefiles, one of which was working, and one which produced the error.

Both had properly tabbed lines, and both had "CRLF" line endings.

For one reason or another, **I managed to fix the problem by changing the line endings to "LF"**, but I am confused as to why the other makefile was parsed successfully even though it had "CRLF" endings. There is, however, a clue: the first one or two times, "make" gave another error:

```
mksh: Warning: newline is not last character...
```

After opening the makefile in a text-editor, and adding a line ending at the end, it started producing the OP's error.

In this situation, it's good to have an editor that can display line endings and tabs.